# Extract lines with specific patterns in separate files

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

The input file has the following lines and segregate these using the 2nd field '+' symbol lines in one file and '-' symbol lines in another file:

```
24 +  I am the Five man    
22 -  Who are you?  The new number two!    
51 +  . . . And four on the floor    
42 +    
16 -  Who is number one?    
33 -  I three you.
```

is it possible when the $2 is '+', a=$1+500 and b=$1-500 at the same time when the $2 is '-', a=$1-500 and b=$1+500? 'a' and 'b' are the new variables.

Comment: is it possible to segregate above lines in two files basing on 2nd field, which is having '+' and '-' symbol using awk...

Comment: is it possible when the $2 is '+', a=$1+500 and b=$1-500 at the same time when the $2 is '-', a=$1-500 and b=$1+500? 'a' and 'b' are the new variables...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will put the "+" lines in file1 and the others in file2:

```
awk '{print > ("file" ($2~/+/?1:2))}' file
```

Comment: Hello Ed Morton, now I need to take the 1st field which are having '+' sign and assign to new variables by adding 500 and subtracting 500 of each record.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign to new variables"? Just update your question with your new requirements along with sample input and expected output or open a new question.

Answer (score 5):

Another option

```
awk 'BEGIN{m["+"]="plus.txt";m["-"]="minus.txt"} $2 ~ /^[+-]$/{print>>m[$2]}'
```

Answer (score 5):

With Perl:

```
perl -lne '/^\d+ -/ && print(STDERR) || print' input 2> minus > plus
```

in a slightly different form:

```
perl -lpe 'select(/^\d+ -/?STDERR:STDOUT)' input 2> minus > plus
```

Also possible using `tee`:

```
tee >(sed -n '/^[0-9]* -/p' > minus) < input | \
   sed -n '/^[0-9]* +/p' > plus
```

Answer (score 4):

This solution filters the output to files f1 and f2.

```
awk '{ if ($2 == "+") print >>"f1"; else if ($2=="-") print >>"f2"; }' datafile
```

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed '/\S\+\s\++/!D' file > plus.txt
sed '/\S\+\s\++/D' file > minus.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` you would simply do:

```
awk '$2=="+"{print>"f1";next}{print>"f2"}' file
```

**Demo:**

```
$ cat file
24 +  I am the Five man
22 -  Who are you?  The new number two!
51 +  . . . And four on the floor
42 +
16 -  Who is number one?
33 -  I three you.

$ awk '$2=="+"{print>"f1";next}{print>"f2"}' file

$ cat f1
24 +  I am the Five man
51 +  . . . And four on the floor
42 +

$ cat f2
22 -  Who are you?  The new number two!
16 -  Who is number one?
33 -  I three you.
```

Comment: Hello sudo_O, now I need to take the 1st field which are having '+' sign and assign to new variables by adding 500 and subtracting 500 of each record.

Answer (score -1):

The question's title is a bit unclear, I'll edit it in a moment. Meanwhile here's the answer:

```
awk '/^[0-9]+ \+/{print > "a"} /^[0-9]+ -/{print > "b"}'
```

Comment: You mean `'$2=="+" {print > "a"} $2=="-" {print > "b"}'`

Comment: @Nirk OK, I thought the first number was just a line number inserted by the editor and not part of the input file. Fixing the expression to handle that.